# How to chop off list at point where number of spaces does not match number of spaces in last elem in Python

Tags: python, list, algorithm, loops, list-comprehension

Say I have a list

```
lst = ['hello world', 'los angeles', 'burgers', 'jacky', '12345', '1 1 1 1', '1 2 3 4', '4 3 2 1']
```

I want to start counting from the end, so  element '4 3 2 1', see that it has 3 spaces in there, and keep everything to the left that also has 3 spaces until it reaches '12345' because it does not have 3 spaces.
How would I achieve something like that? I don't want to hard code it to keep iterating until it reaches 0 spaces, because '12345' could change to something like '123 45'.
Final output would be:

```
['1 1 1 1', '1 2 3 4', '4 3 2 1']
```

Comment: If you `.split()` each element of the list, the length of the resulting list will be 4 for `'4 3 2 1'` and 1 for `'12345'`

Comment: Be aware that counting spaces is fragile. For example, the string `' 4 3 '` has three spaces, but only two numbers. And a string that contains TAB characters could have four numbers, and no spaces.

Comment: yes, i made sure to strip off leading and trailing spaces before, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over your list in reverse, capture values with 3 spaces, and break when it hits something that doesn't have 3 spaces. The output list will be in that same reverse order, so if you want it in its original order, you need to print that reversed as well.

To make it dynamic, you can set the space count to a variable by counting the spaces in the last element of your initial list:

```
# initial list
lst = ['hello world', 'los angeles', 'burgers', 'jacky', '12345', '1 1 1 1', '1 2 3 4', '4 3 2 1']

# get the space count from the last element
space_count = lst[-1].count(' ')

# make output list to hold values
output_list = []

# iterate in reverse and gather elements with 
# correct space count and stop when it hits first
# element without that space count
for x in lst[::-1]:
     if x.count(' ') == space_count:
         output_list.append(x)
     else:
         break
print(output_list[::-1])
```

Comment: how could we get rid of the hard coded '3' to make it read the last elem of the list, count num spaces, and use that as the num we want to compare to?

Comment: @JerryStackhouse Just use another variable and check the space count. Added to the answer.